# How to fetch value inside a Nested JSON in Snowflake (based on value present inside the same JSON)

Tags: arrays, json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, flatten

I have a JSON object as show below:

```
{"K":"5",
"DE":[
{"H[1]":"1-162001524"},
{"H[2]":"2-162001534"},
{"H[3]":"3-162001540"},
{"H[4]":"5-162001559"},
{"H[5]":"6-162001563"}
]
}
```

Now, i want data from DE array based on the value in K in my select query. So, from the above example it should give me the value for H[5] i.e. 6-162001563.
I have tried few different things but no luck.

Can someone help me out on this?

Disclaimer: I'm not a JSON expert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't the most eloquent, but it works.  Assuming I create a CTE with the following statement to resemble your JSON data:

```
WITH x as (
    SELECT parse_json('{"K":"5",
          "DE":[
          {"H[1]":"1-162001524"},
          {"H[2]":"2-162001534"},
          {"H[3]":"3-162001540"},
          {"H[4]":"5-162001559"},
          {"H[5]":"6-162001563"}
          ]
          }') as var
  )
```

You can then flatten the array, search for the value based on a `get_path()` statement where you'd have to parse together the K value and the extra characters to produce your path.  This gives you all records from the array, but then searching for non-NULL records, you'd get the output you are looking for.

```
SELECT get_path(y.value,'"H['||x.var:K::varchar||']"')::varchar as output
FROM x,
LATERAL FLATTEN(input=>var:DE) y
WHERE output IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @mikewalton. It worked fine. My source column containing the JSON is a varchar. So, i had to tweak the query a little bit and add PARSE_JSON and it worked smoothly.

Comment: @Kshitij Glad I could help.  If you found this solution to be the answer to your question, feel free to mark it as the correct answer.  Thanks.